# Problema no instanciamento usando pdo/Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class

Tags: html, pdo

O Seguinte erro aparece ao tentar instanciar e chamar um determinado método:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Usuario' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Projetos\relatorios.php:126 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projetos\relatorios.php on line 126

A primeira tela contem o formulário da busca e a segunda, é onde vai ser apresentado o resultado.

O código a seguir é da tela que exibe o resultado.

```
<?php
    require 'queryconection.php';

    //Instanciando a classe
    $Usuario new Usuario();
    $listaDados = $Usuario->carregaSetores($setor, $host, $month);

    if (!empty($listaDados)) {
        foreach ($listaDados as  $value) {
            echo "<pre>"; 
            print_r($value);
            exit();

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><center>". $value["setor"] ."</center></td>";
                echo "<td><center>". $value["usuario"] ."</center></td>";
                echo "<td><center>". $value["hd"] ."</center></td>";
                echo "<td>". $value["memoria"] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $value["processador"] ."</td>";
                echo "<td><center>". $value["cd"] ."</center></td>";
                echo "<td><center>". $value["placam"] ."</center></td>";
                echo "<td>". $value["host"] ."</td>";
                echo "<td>". $value["monitor"] ."</td>";
                echo "<td><center>". $value["nobreak"] ."</center></td>";
                echo "<td><center>". $value["placar"] ."</center></td>";
                echo "<td>". $value["placav"] ."</td>";
            echo "</tr >";
        }
    }
?>
```

**Essa é minha query , quem conseguir resolver meu erro dou os ponto**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "cadastro";

//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "cadastro");
if ($link->connect_errno) {
    echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
    exit();
}

function carregaSetores($setor,$host,$month){               
    try {
        $Query = "SELECT 
                s.setor,
                s.usuario,
                s.hd,
                s.memoria,
                s.cd,
                s.placam,
                s.host,
                s.monitor,
                s.nobreak,
                s.placar,
                s.placav
            FROM setor            
        ";

        $p_sql = mysql::getInstance()->prepare($Query);
        $_retorno = array(); 

        if ($p_sql->execute()) {
            while ($_result = $p_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
                $_retorno[] = $_result; 
            }
        }

        return $_retorno;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Lembre de colocar o sinal de atribuição (`=`) nessa linha `$Usuario new Usuario();`. vc não precisa deletar a pergunta e faze-la novamente, basta fazer uma edição.

Comment: @rray você poderia colocar como resposta a pegunta assim tanto eu quanto outros posso se beneficiar .

Comment: Isso resolveu o problema?

Comment: Não , continua não aparecendo nada na tela , tipo dei um echo "<pre>"; print_r($Usuario); exit;  e mesmo assim não aparece nada .

Comment: Se der um `print_r($listaDados)` aparece alguma coisa?

Comment: Não , aparece tela em branco também .

Comment: @rray deu certo colocando o = na linha que você disso , obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente não existe nenhuma classe usuário definida em seu código. Seria interessante separar o segundo trecho de sua pergunta e criar um arquivo específico para a classe usuário que terá a função `carregaSetores`. Veja:

**Arquivo database/connection.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "cadastro";

$dbConnetion = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "cadastro");
if ($link->connect_errno) {
    echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
    exit();
}
```

**Arquivo classes/usuario.php**

```
<?php
class Usuario {
    private $connection = null;

    public function __construction($connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function carregaSetores($setor, $host, $month) {
        try {
            $Query = "SELECT 
                    s.setor,
                    s.usuario,
                    s.hd,
                    s.memoria,
                    s.cd,
                    s.placam,
                    s.host,
                    s.monitor,
                    s.nobreak,
                    s.placar,
                    s.placav
                FROM setor as s   
            ";

            $p_sql = mysql::getInstance()->prepare($Query);
            $_retorno = array(); 

            if ($p_sql->execute()) {
                while ($_result = $p_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
                    $_retorno[] = $_result; 
                }
            }

            return $_retorno;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Ao utilizar, não se esqueça de dar um `require` nos arquivos. Caso queira descomplicar sua vida e evitar o uso de requires, estude sobre `autoloads` e `namespaces`.

Para utilizar o código ficaria assim:

```
require 'database/connection.php';
require 'classes/usuario.php';

$Usuario = new Usuario($dbConnetion);
$listaDados = $Usuario->carregaSetores($setor, $host, $month);
```

Cuidado com a forma como utiliza a variável onde está gravada a conexão, você pode sobrescrever sem querer o calor dela e perder horas tentando descobrir o que está errado.

**Algumas observações**

Você pode fazer várias melhorias em seu código, uma das principais é a formatação. Utilize um padrão que a comunidade vem adotando ([Página original](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) e em [Português](https://github.com/andreia/fig-standards-pt-BR/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md), assim seu código será muito melhor visto pelo mercado, além de ficar bem mais fácil de identificar os problemas enfrentados durante o desenvolvimento.

Comment: Olá fiz tudo que está recomentado acima só que tentei de tudo e aparece esses erros .                Warning: require(Projetos/connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projetos\relatorios.php on line 124

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Projetos/connection.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projetos\relatorios.php on line 124

Comment: O seu script está na pasta projetos, então só precisa colocar `require(connection.php);`

Answer (score 0):

Alterar a quarta linha de:

```
$Usuario new Usuario();
```

para:

```
$Usuario = new Usuario();
```